# Многоуровневый каталог товаров в мобильном приложении для iPhone и iPad

Tags: ipad, мобильные-приложения, ios, iphone, мобильная-разработка

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Несколько дней назад, в качестве хобби, решил заняться разработкой мобильных приложений для iPhone и iPad. Поставил себе задачу реализовать многоуровневый оффлайн-каталог товаров. Максимальный уровень вложенности разделов - 5.
Почитал документацию, посмотрел видеоуроки и никак не могу понять, как создать такую вложенность. С помощью Xcode нашел и скачал демо-пример проекта DynamicsCatalog.
Но в нем иерархия довольно простая.

Имеется таблица, со строками. В каждой строке есть заголовок. Нажимаем на заголовок, попадаем на детальную страницу.

Ниже структура main.storyboard:

```
->NavigationController->TableViewController
                            |->TableViewCell->push segue ->UIViewController
```

Т.е. для каждой строки назначен отдельный UIViewController, и они связаны с помощью push segue.

Вопрос. Неужели, для каталога товаров необходимо создавать отдельный view для каждого уровня? А если уровней со временем станет 7?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону нужно копать?

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Извиняюсь за неверную терминологию.

UPD: Нашел вот такое решение https://toster.ru/q/81

Но это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Хочется сделать поведение каталога, аналогичным поведению каталога на сайтах. Например, ozon.ru.

Первый уровень вложенности:

1. Книги
2. Электроника
3. Бытовая техника

Переходим в Книги

1. Бизнес литература
2. Биографии
3. И т.д.

Переходим в Бизнес литературу

1. Деловая литература
2. Кадры ...
3. И т.д.

Причем в каждом разделе еще отображаются некоторые топовые товары. 
Как возможно реализовать нечто подобное?

Comment: А вьюхи координально разные? Почему нельзя создавать одну и туже вьюху с разными данными? Вызывайте рекурсивно тоже самый контроллер  и все.. пока память не кончится хоть 100n вложенность будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать, одним Interface Builder'ом не реализовать. Реализуйте методы UITableViewDataSource и UITableViewDelegate для таблицы. Аналогично для UINavigationController'a. Вложенность может быть сколь угодно большой(в разумных пределах).